# Array output miscellaneous

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a=3, b = 6;
printf(&a["Hi!Hello! %s\n"], &b["Mnnit/Softathalon"]);
printf(&a["WHAT%c%c%c %c%c %c !\n"], 1["this"],
2["beauty"],0["tool"],0["is"],3["sensitive"],4["CCCCCC"]);
return 0;
}
```

output:

> Hello! Softathalon
>
> That is C !

Why is this the output? Can anyone explain different format specifier in it?

Comment: Like... why is `a[i]` the same as `i[a]`? Or `str[4]` the same as `4[str]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any array `T arr[N]`, the expression `arr[i]` is equivalent to `*(arr + i)`.

Because the addition is commutative in the latter expression, you can also write this as `*(i + arr)`, and hence as `i[arr]`.

In particular, `arr[3]` and `3[arr]` denote the same thing.

It's one of those "curiously funny things you can do in C", but it should go without saying that serious code should never actually use such a construction.